# WooCommerce - Hide products with same title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to hide products with same title from shop page.
I have many products with different SKU but same name.

Is it possible to achieve that with a distinct function like this or should i create a custom loop?

```
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', function ( $distinct ) {
    //if same name update_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', '_visibility_search' );
return 'DISTINCT'; });
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you like to hide it when it's not the same product and customer would want to buy the hidden one..

Comment: The only difference is the color and customer will be able to choose the products that i want to hide through the single-product page. I want to hide them only in Shop page loop. In single-product page I'm using a function that displays same name products with the main product.

Comment: @Billy Is this an XY problem? I think you could take advantage of [Variable Products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) for this.

Comment: It's a bit strange and i can't answer that because it's a long story but this solution isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've found the solution by using a function, in case anyone in the future needs it.

```
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'custom_posts_groupby', 10, 2 );
function custom_posts_groupby( $groupby, $query ) {
     global $wpdb;

     if ( is_main_query() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_search() )) {
         $groupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title";
     }

     return $groupby;
}
```